# How to get the value of a input box in a single product page and display it in the admin section?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, sales-order

I have a input box on **Product detail page**, to enter a message. I want that message to be display in **Items Ordered** section asAdditional Information column in product table.

My input box is

```
<input type="text" placeholder="eg., Happy Birthday!" id="msg">
```

Can anyone say how to get the value of input box and display in the additional information column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Custom option here is a process to set Custom option for the product . In your case, u use text type Custom option

Custom options are an easy way to offer a selection of product variations that do not rely on attributes. The limitations are that you cannot track inventory based on any variation and that a product with custom options cannot be used with a configurable, grouped, or bundle product. Custom options are a good solution if your inventory needs are simple.

To create custom options:

1. On the Admin menu, select Catalog > Manage Products.
2. In the list, open the product record in edit mode.
3. In the panel on the left, select Custom Options.
4. In the upper-right corner, click the Add New Option button. Then, do the following:
   a.  In the Title field, enter a name for the property.
   b.  Set the Input Type you want to use for data entry.
   c.  Set Is Required to “Yes” if the option must be selected before the product can be purchased.
   d.  In the Sort Order field, enter a number to indicate the order of this item in the list of options. Enter the number 1 to display this option first.

[image]

5. Click the Add New Row button. Then, complete the following:

   [image]

**[Source](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html)**

Comment: I have cakes as products in the website. for the products of cakes in its single page I wanted a single input field to enter the message to be written on the particular. Can custom option be used to do this task ?

Comment: Yes once try to use custom option

Comment: The input field content will only come in the items ordered section in order tab in magento admin panel.. I what to display it in the additional information section in the order tab in admin panel .. how to do that ?

Comment: I can't understand.Can you please edit your answer with screenshot

Comment: Additional information section in the order tab in admin panel i don't know where this place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47502/discussion-between-vaibhav-ahalpara-and-lena).

Comment: Hi.. But for each new products when added by the clients in the backend, they have to create the input text field and enter the title in the custom option..

Comment: you have all simple product ?

Comment: http://doghouse.agency/article/magento-adding-message-product-during-purchase

Comment: The client will be also giving the products from the backend. So when they are giving the products from the backend, they should also add custom option for each products being added..

Comment: there are many ways to do this 1) client need to add option while creating product. 2) you can call observer  catalog_product_prepare_save and add custom option programmatically. 3) You have add text box in view.phtm when customer add product to cart use this value and set value to product

Comment: if using custom option, if client has to add the custom option, is it a problm /?

Comment: This is a better solution.

Comment: will it not be difficult for the client ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the custom option for those type of product. Custom option must be type `text`.

This will come with order and default available in Admin.

> Remove your input box of product view page, this will auto create that input box